# memory leak after free?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I have noticed the program I have been testing leaks memory at two different points, no matter if I call `free()` or not. I don't understand why it's happening and how it could be fixed.

I am using leaks to test for memory leaks: no Valgrind available for my machine.

Here's the report:

```
leaks Report Version: 4.0, multi-line stacks
Process 21334: 226 nodes malloced for 18 KB
Process 21334: 2 leaks for 544 total leaked bytes.

STACK OF 1 INSTANCE OF 'ROOT LEAK: <malloc in tokenizer>':
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x18d51eda0 thread_start + 8
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x18d523fa8 _pthread_start + 148
1   a.out                                 0x102c13c10 tokenizer + 36
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib                0x18d364d88 _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy + 128 
====
    1 (272 bytes) ROOT LEAK: <malloc in tokenizer 0x120004080> [272]

STACK OF 1 INSTANCE OF 'ROOT LEAK: <calloc in printwords>':
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x18d51eda0 thread_start + 8
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x18d523fa8 _pthread_start + 148
1   a.out                                 0x102c13d4c printwords + 40
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib                0x18d364eb0 _malloc_zone_calloc_instrumented_or_legacy + 92 
====
    1 (272 bytes) ROOT LEAK: <calloc in printwords 0x11ef041d0> [272]
```

It is a multi-threaded program that reads a text file, separates the words and then prints them. This version does not print the words but the memory leaks are the exact same (I've tested it).

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "functs.h"


pthread_t *thpool;
Deque_t* deque_12;
Deque_t* deque_23;

void* readfile(void* arg);
void* tokenizer();
void* printwords();
char rd;
char tk;


void init(){
   deque_12 = new_deque();
   deque_23 = new_deque();
   rd = 0; //lines read
   tk = 0; //all lines tokenized
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   
   char* filename = "loremIpsum.txt";
   init();
   thpool = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*3);
   
   thread_create(&thpool[0],/*attrs*/ NULL, readfile, (void*)filename);
   thread_create(&thpool[1],/*attrs*/ NULL, tokenizer, /*args*/NULL);
   thread_create(&thpool[2],/*attrs*/ NULL, printwords, /*args*/NULL);

   
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
      thread_join(thpool[i], NULL);
   
   free_deque(deque_12,1);
   free_deque(deque_23,0);
   free(thpool);
}

void* readfile(void* arg){
   FILE* fp= fopen((char*)arg, "r");
   
   char* line= calloc(1,sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
   while(fgets(line, BUFSIZE, fp)!=NULL){
      push_tail(deque_12, (void*)line);
      line= calloc(1,sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
   }
   rd=1;
   printf("1: File read\n");
   fclose(fp);
   free(line);
   return NULL; 
}

void* tokenizer(){
   struct timespec t = {0,1000000};
   while(isEmpty(deque_12))
      nanosleep(&t, NULL);
   char* bfr = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE); //memory leak
   while(1){
      pop_head(deque_12, (void*)&bfr,1);
      if(bfr==NULL && rd) break;
      else if(bfr==NULL){
         nanosleep(&t, NULL);
         continue;
      }
      char* state;
      char* token = strtok_r(bfr, " ",&state);
      while(token!=NULL){
         push_tail(deque_23, (void*)token);
         token = strtok_r(NULL, " ",&state);
      }
   }
   free(bfr);
   tk=1;
   puts("2: Tokenized");
   return NULL;
}
void* printwords(){
   struct timespec t = {0,1000000};
   char* word= calloc(1, sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE); //memory leak
   while(1){
      pop_head(deque_23, (void*)&word,0);
      if(word==NULL && tk) break;
      else if(word==NULL){
         nanosleep(&t, NULL);
         continue;
      }
      printf(">%s\n",word);
      fflush(stdout);
   }
   puts("3: all words printed");
   free(word);
   return NULL;
}
```

functs.h:

```
#ifndef _FUNCTS_H
#define _FUNCTS_H

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef BUFSIZE
#define BUFSIZE 256
#endif

void thread_create(pthread_t *tid,const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg){
    int err;
    if((err = pthread_create(tid, attr, start_routine, arg)) != 0){
        perror("pthread_create");
        errno = err;
        pthread_exit(&errno);
    }
}
void thread_join(pthread_t tid, void **retval){
    int err;
    if((err = pthread_join(tid, retval)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"FATAL_ERROR: thread_join");
        errno = err;
        pthread_exit(&errno);
    }
}
void mtx_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mtx_ptr){
    int err;
    if((err = pthread_mutex_lock(mtx_ptr)) != 0){
        puts("mutex_lock");
        errno = err;
        pthread_exit(&errno);
    }
}
void mtx_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mtx_ptr){
    int err;
    if((err = pthread_mutex_unlock(mtx_ptr)) != 0){
        perror("mutex_unlock");
        errno = err;
        pthread_exit(&errno);
    }       
}


typedef struct node{
   void* data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}Node_t;

typedef struct deque{
   Node_t *head;
   Node_t *tail;
   pthread_mutex_t mtx;
}Deque_t;

Deque_t* new_deque(){
   Deque_t* d = malloc(sizeof(Deque_t));
   d->head = NULL;
   d->tail = NULL;
   pthread_mutex_init(&(d->mtx), NULL);
   return d;
}

int isEmpty(Deque_t *d){
   return (d->head == NULL);
}
void push_tail(Deque_t* d, void* data){
   Node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node_t));
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = NULL;
   mtx_lock(&(d->mtx));

   if(isEmpty(d)){
      newNode->prev = NULL;
      d->head = newNode;
   }
   else{
      newNode->prev = d->tail;
      d->tail->next = newNode;
   }
   d->tail = newNode;
   mtx_unlock(&(d->mtx));
}
void pop_head(Deque_t* d, void** val, int ismallocd){
   mtx_lock(&(d->mtx));
   if(isEmpty(d)){
      mtx_unlock(&(d->mtx));
      *val = NULL;
      return;
   }
   Node_t *tmp = d->head;
   *val = d->head->data;
   if(d->head == d->tail){
      d->head = NULL;
      d->tail = NULL;
   }
   else{
      d->head = d->head->next;
      d->head->prev = NULL;
   }
   mtx_unlock(&(d->mtx));
   if(ismallocd) free(tmp->data);
   free(tmp);
} 
void free_deque(Deque_t* d, int ismallocd){
   Node_t* tmp;
   while(d->head != NULL){
      tmp = d->head;
      d->head = d->head->next;
      if(ismallocd) free(tmp->data);
      free(tmp);
    }
    free(d);
}
#endif
```

Comment: @Mat yes. `if(bfr==NULL && rd) break` exits the loop. the program ends correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `printwords` function, you allocate memory in the following line:

```c
char* word= calloc(1, sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
```

You *attempt* to free that memory near the end of the function, with:

```c
free(word);
```

However, by that point (i.e. when the `while(1)` loop has been broken), the `word` pointer ***must be*** `NULL`, because the only way out of that loop is in the `if(word==NULL && tk) break;` line. Remember that calling the `free` function with a `NULL` argument is not an error and has well-defined (by the C Standard) behaviour: It does nothing.

I'm not *entirely* sure why you make that allocation (possibly, so that you can pass a non-null pointer to the `pop_head` function); however, if you want to do that, you should allocate it to a *different* variable and then copy that to the `word` pointer used in the loop.

Here's a way you can do this:

```c
void* printwords()
{
   struct timespec t = {0,1000000};
   char* temp = calloc(1, sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
   char* word = temp; // We can use that local allocation but we MUST remember it!
   while(1) {
      pop_head(deque_23, (void*)&word,0);
      if(word==NULL && tk) break;
      else if(word==NULL){
         nanosleep(&t, NULL);
         continue;
      }
      printf(">%s\n",word);
      fflush(stdout);
   }
   puts("3: all words printed");
// free(word); // WRONG! At this point, "word" is NULL
   free(temp); // Should work!
   return NULL;
}
```

You could, alternatively, handle the `free()` for that allocated `char` buffer inside the `pop_head` function (e.g., with `free(*val)` before you set `*val = NULL;` and return), but that *may* interfere with the proper working of your list deletion process.

Note that you have the exact same problem with your `bfr` buffer, in the `tokenizer` function, and the remedy is the same.

Comment: Didn't think about the fact I could declare the pointer without allocation lmao, it really was an overlooked mistake. If I ever need to allocate it, I now know I should make a temp variable beforehand. Thanks a lot!